# How can I use non-TF environmental variables in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Let's say I want to read `$HOME` in Terraform. I could create a variable called `HOME` and set it with `TF_HOME`, ie.,

```
TF_HOME=$HOME terraform apply
```

But is there a way to read `$HOME` directly in Terraform?

---

I know about [`pathexpand`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/pathexpand) which solves this issue for `HOME`, I'm just wanting more information as to whether or not Terraform can access any environmental variable and used it as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Workaround (official solution)

You can not access the environmental variables through an official API. However, you can access the output of a script as a workaround. To access environmental variables external to the `TF_` prefix, you must

- Create a script to output the variable, you can wrap that output in JSON.
- Run that script as an [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source)
- Read from the output of the script.

For more information on this approach check out,

- https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4547786359571-Reading-and-using-environment-variables-in-Terraform-runs

Answer (score 1):

From Terraform's perspective, environment variables are just another kind of data from outside of Terraform and so if you want to read from them then you'd do so using a [data source](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources) designed for that purpose.

Using data sources for external data means that there's a well-defined model for when Terraform will access the data and a guarantee that Terraform will access it only once per plan and apply, either during the plan phase if possible or during the apply phase if the data source configuration depends on information not available until the apply step.

There is not an official provider for accessing environment variables because in most cases a Terraform configuration should not directly depend on anything about the specific system where it's running -- a typical Terraform configuration is for managing remote objects via network APIs -- but there are some third party providers in the registry whose documentation suggests that they might give you what you need:

- [`environment_variables`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/EppO/environment/latest/docs/data-sources/variables) from the provider `EppO/environment`.
- [`environment_variable`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/MorganPeat/environment/latest/docs/data-sources/variable) from the provider `MorganPeat/environment`.

I have not directly used either so I cannot specifically recommend either of these. I suggest reviewing the documentation and the source code to see if they can do what you need.